# perl Net::IMAP::Client how to get unseen emails

Tags: perl, email, imap

I am using Net::IMAP::Client

Code:

```
my $imap = Net::IMAP::Client->new(
   server => 'imap.server.com',
   user   => $user,
   pass   => $pass,
   ssl    => 1,                              # (use SSL? default no)
   ssl_verify_peer => 0,                     # (use ca to verify server, default yes)
   #ssl_ca_file => '/etc/ssl/certs/certa.pm', # (CA file used for verify server) or
   # ssl_ca_path => '/etc/ssl/certs/',         # (CA path used for SSL)
   port   => 993                             # (but defaults are sane)

) or die "Could not connect to IMAP server";


$imap->login or die('Login failed: ' . $imap->last_error);
$imap->select('INBOX');
```

Then I tried:

```
my $status = $imap->status(INBOX);
```

Now I have hash like this:

```
name : INBOX 
UIDNEXT : 312 
MESSAGES : 298 
RECENT : 0 
UNSEEN : 1 
UIDVALIDITY : 1420542773
```

Now want to get text of this one unseen e-mail.
I read documentation but didnt find how to do that.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Show us your code. Have you tried reading the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::IMAP::Client)?

Answer (score 0):

I have code which I know is working. It uses a different module, but may get you where you need to go?

```
use Mail::IMAPClient;

sub get_imap {
  my ($user, $pass) = @_;
  my $imap = Mail::IMAPClient->new(  
    'User'    => $user,
    'Password'=> $pass,
    'Ssl'     => 1 ) or die "IMAP Failure: $@";
  $imap->Timeout(120);
  $imap->Server('smtp.gmail.com');
  $imap->connect or die "Could not connect: $@\n";
  $imap->select('Inbox') or die "IMAP Select Error: $!";

  return $imap;
}

sub check_msgs {
  my ($imap) = @_;

  my @msgs = $imap->messages or die "Could not get messages: $@\n";

  MSGITR:   
  foreach my $msg_id (@msgs) {
    print "looking at msg_id $msg_id\n";
    my $string = $imap->body_string($msg_id);
    my @lines  = split( /[\n\r]/, $string );
    print scalar @lines . " lines\n";
    foreach my $line (@lines) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

(actual snippet from my working code, which checks messages for bounces)